# How to render a component inside render method?

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app like this

```
import Modal from 'some-component'


class Blog extends React.Component {



render () { 
 <Modal title='' content='' onOk='' onClose=''/> 
 <SomeComponent> </SomeComponent>
}

}
```

I am trying to use a separate function to render the modal, and call that function inside the render method like this

```
...
renderModal = () => {}

render() {
 // call renderModal here
 <SomeComponent> </SomeComponent>
}
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: You forgot to `return` the html inside your render function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
renderModal = () => {
return (........your html....);
}
render () {
   {this.renderModal()};
}
```

You can use this code to get what you are asking..

Answer (score 2):

```
render () { 
  return (
   <Modal title='' content='' onOk='' onClose=''/> 
   <SomeComponent> </SomeComponent>
  )
}
```

you should wrap them in a parent element =>

```
render () {
  return (
     <>
      <Modal title='' content='' onOk='' onClose=''/> 
      <SomeComponent> </SomeComponent>
     </>
  )
}
```

then you can use

```
renderModal = () => <Modal title='' content='' onOk='' onClose='' />

render () { 
 return (
  <>
   {this.renderModal()}
   <SomeComponent> </SomeComponent>
  </>
  )
 }
```